# Include and reference an image in react with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, singlepage

What ist the best way to include and reference images for react-usage in a singlepage JavaScript app build and bundled with webpack?

So far i have

```
return (<img src={require('./pic.png'}</div>)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Depending on the situation, sometimes a spritesheet makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Webpack's [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack/url-loader) you can tell it to automatically embed a data uri if the file size is under a specified limit.

```
require("url?limit=10000!./pic.png");
// => DataUrl if "pic.png" is smaller that 10kb
```